# How to do orderBy on custom field in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have taken count for number of products on each user

```
qb.loadRelationCountAndMap('user.products_count', 'user.products');
```

Now I want to do order by on this field

```
qb.orderBy(`user.products_count`, 'DESC');
```

and I am trying to do orderBy but giving error

```
response: 'Cannot read property \'databaseName\' of undefined',
status: 500,
message: 'Cannot read property \'databaseName\' of undefined' } false
```

I am using it with pagination getManyAndCount().

Comment: You can simply create an alias and order by that alias name. I'd need more code / information to give you a full solution though.